# How can I Play a simple .WAV on UWP

Tags: uwp, wav

Is there any simple way to play a .wav file on a button's click event in UWP with no delay?
All the methods I've tried have slight annoying delay

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a media element programmatically, set the source to the audio file and call Play.

```
var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/audio.mp3");
mediaElement.Play();
```